# 3d Matrix elements combinations

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix

I got this little project for school. I have a 3d matrix (char*** valueArray) which holds info (functions name, functions parameters, and parameters value)

e.g. I have 3 functions

```
int fnc1(int a,long b,long c);

void fnc2(char a, int b);

void fnc3();
```

My matrix will hold the function number,the parameters, and the parameters value (each parameter has 3 values:minimum,0,maximum). If I want the info about fnc1, parameter 2, value 3 I will be using `valueArray[1][2][3]` and so on, basically the first number means what function it is,the second what parameter, and the third the value (min-0-max).

The task: For every function display all the possible combinations created using the 3 parameters values.

Something like this:

```
for fnc1,
amin-bmin-cmin/
amin-bmin-c0/
amin-bmin-cmax/
amin-b0-cmin/
amin-b0-c0/
amin-b0-cmax
........./amax-bmax-cmax
```

the indexes will be something like this

```
111 121 131 //new row// 
111 121 132 // new row//
111 121 133 //new row//
111 122 131 //new row//
111 122 132 //new row//
111 122 133//new row//
.....
```

The 3-for-3-print thing from below works perfect for a function with 3 parameters (because I use a print for every value) but I need it to work for every function, no matter how many parameters the function has and making a switch for every case is not an option because I don't know how many parameters will a function have (the teacher may put a function with 10 parameter just to test me).

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    for(k=0;k<3;k++)
      printf("%s %s %s\n",valueArray[0][0][i],valueArray[0][1][j],valueArray[0][2][k]);
```

Can anyone give me some hints about how can I do this?

Comment: You need to somehow hint yourself how many parameters a function has.
You could, for instance, store an empty string to indicate a blank parameter, or a NULL... Then you could just stop the 2nd loop

Comment: Indeed, i can figure out how many parameters has a function, but let's say it has 4, i will need to add another for, and 1 more for 5 and so on..
It is the same as a switch in which i will have to do a print for every case(not so great for 10 parameters).I also tought to search wich functions has the biggest number of parameters and do the print for it,and the rest of the functions will be ok.But in a function with fewer parametrs than the maximum number,i have pointers errors(the print will try to display an inexistent thing)

Comment: No, you just need another breaking condition for your loops like
`if (valueArray[i][j][k] == NULL) break`

Comment: if i put a function with 4 parameters, the 3 for structures won't work

Comment: `char*** valueArray` is not a 3D array (something like 3D matrix does not exist) nor can it point ot one. A pointer is not an array! If you want a 3D array, use one, resp. a pointer to a 2D array. As a sidenote: Being a 3-star C programmer is not a compliment. It is a signal of a bad interface design.

Comment: @SilviuAlexandru Sounds like you need a dynamic array with dynamic allocations...
And then, you must also supply the array size.
You can't have it all...